# Zip a scheduled report in Cognos

Tags: cognos, cognos-10

How to Zip a scheduled csv format report in IBM Cognos. I tried to convert the report into active report and compress it but it produces a .mht file instead of zip.

Answer (score 0):

You could try scheduling the report with a delivery setting of Email along with setting the compression settings on the delivery service as noted here:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEP7J_10.2.2/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.ug_cc.10.2.2.doc/t_asg_config_email_attachments.html

If that does not work you could also enable the output to file system and then write a script which takes care of the compression after the fact.

https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-save-report-outputs-file-location-report-basis